# Match everything between empty lines

Tags: regex

I have text formatted like this:

```
(empty line)
stuff here
more stuff here
maybe even more here
(empty line)
stuff here
more stuff here
maybe even more here
(empty line)
```

I need to grab what's between the empty lines. I tried `^\s*$.+?^\s*$` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you use any programming language?

Comment: Also what's your expected output?

Comment: See a [PCRE approach - `^\R(.*?)(?=\R{2}|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/W3nGAQ/1).

Comment: @baao I'm using the Construct 2 software, but it should have a pretty standard regex implementation

Comment: @anubhava I'm trying to count the instances with RegexMatchCount(AJAX.LastData, "^\s*$.+?^\s*$", "gim")

Comment: Try a split using `(?m)(?>^\s*\R)`

Comment: _Empty Line_ is ambiguous since there are no holes in text. This `"  \r \t \f    \r  \r   \r\n"` is an empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?:\r?\n|^)((?:\r?\n|.)+?)(?=\r?\n\r?\n|$)
```

- `(?:\r?\n|^)` Matches the beginning of the string or a line break (`\r\n` for Windows, `\n` for UNIX)
- `((?:\r?\n|.)+?)` Matches any character including line breaks at least one time, but non-greedy, includes it into a group `$1`
- `(?=\r?\n\r?\n|$)` Marks a double line break or the end of the string `$` as the end of the match. This is done with a positive lookahead to prevent including the double line break into the match.
- Make sure to use the global flag `/g`.

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/69gLk9/1

---

You could also use the `split()` function of many programming languages in combination with the following regular expression:

```
\r?\n\r?\n
```

```js
var text = "This is text.\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\n\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\n\nThis is text.\nThis is text.\n\nThis is text.\nThis is text.";
var regex = /\r?\n\r?\n/g;

var match = text.split(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: _`(?:\r?\n|.) Matches any character`_ - usually not _\r_. The default dot meta-character means `[^\r\n]` and is probably platform specific. But you can't trust how any given text exists as binary.

Comment: Yes, but the `\r` character is not widely used anymore. `\r\n` however is still used.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/iz1sBw/2) is answer to your question.

```
`/^\n((?:\n|.)*?)\n$/gm`
```

### How it works:

`^\n` starting with end of line so line must be empty
`((?:\n|.)*?)` capture any count of new line or any char
`\n$` end with end line char

don't forget to add `global` and `multiline` flag